# "Too many connections for role" error in Heroku (with Ebean)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework, ebean

I'm using the configuration below for Ebean, so normally there shouldn't be more than 20 connections open, which is the limit for the Hobby-basic plan that I use in Heroku. Even so, Heroku is throwing the error: `FATAL: too many connections for role...` from time to time. Any clues?

```
db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=20
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=2
db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=3
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=30 seconds
db.default.connectionTimeout=30 seconds
db.default.idleMaxAge=5 minutes
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=0
db.default.maxConnectionAge=15 minutes
db.default.initSQL="SELECT 1"
db.default.releaseHelperThreads=0
```

Comment: Dumb question: how many dynos are you running?

Comment: One traditional dyno

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I've had this problem as well (play framework 2.4.3 + ebean). It happened yesterday while Heroku was reporting that I had 11/20 connections, but the app couldn't connect to the database with that same error message.

Now that I think of it, having a connection pool of 10 (when the limit is 20), could it be that something happened, and the app was trying to allocate another pool of 10, while there were 11 connections already open (10 from the app and 1 from the terminal)?

I'm also running 1 web dyno.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. It just happened again minutes ago, despite setting maxConnectionsPerPartition to 15.